# Is it possible for MySQL v5.7.6 to to implement mesh replication with multi-source replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7

As I know starting from MySQL `v5.7.6` the `multi-source` replication is possible. So If we can have a slave that can get data from multiple masters. Can we have mesh replication, where each node act as a slave for all other nodes ?

## Mesh Replication

If we have 4 nodes (N1, N2, N3, N4)

- N1 is a slave for N2, N3, N4.
- N2 is a slave for N1, N3, N4.
- N3 is a slave for N1, N2, N4.
- N4 is a slave for N1, N2, N3.

If yes we can do that ? How nodes detect duplicated events in such scenario:

- A new change in N1 is happened.
- N1 pushes this change into N2, N3, N4.
- The new change is received at N2 (and the other nodes).
- How N2 does't replicate it again ! Otherwise we will have a infinite loop !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's called Galera.

A write to any node is automatically replicated to all other nodes.

Galera is *usually* deployed in 3-node configuration, but 4 is possible.

It is available from Percona (PXC), MariaDB, or an addon to MySQL.

Please explain *why* you want that configuration.

And, no, Galera won't get into an infinite loop.  Nor will any other multi-master setup -- as long as you set `server-id` to different values on each Master.

Comment: I am not asking about Galera.

Comment: @faressoft - OK, you could simulate some of what Galera does.  But the hard part would be repairing the setup if any node crashes.